# jQuery tooltip offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#demo img[title]").tooltip({effect: 'slide'});
});
```

I want to add an offset to this function, but when i add offset [20, 0], it doesn't work.  I would like to know how to code using 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#demo img[title]").tooltip({effect: 'slide', offset: [10, 2]});
});
```

this should just work fine. If you have a problem, post you code.

Comment: Thanks for your correct and timely answer.  You have helped me greatly. This is my first question, so now I have registered.

Comment: if you find the answer useful, accept it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. this will help other people find the right answer.